# How to server Flutter Web Static assets using embed files Golang without adding every file to router?

Tags: flutter, go, server, assets

I am currently attempting to serve my Flutter Web application as a single binary server using Golang. The solution below works by explicitly calling out every file referred to by index.html

```golang
import (
    "embed"
    "net/http"
)

//go:embed static/*
var staticFiles embed.FS

type Server struct {
    router *mux.Router
}

void main() {

    fsys, err := fs.Sub(staticFiles, "static")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    s.router.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.FS(fsys)))
    s.router.Handle("/flutter.js", http.FileServer(http.FS(fsys)))
    s.router.Handle("/main.dart.js", http.FileServer(http.FS(fsys)))
    s.router.Handle("/assets/FontManifest.json", http.FileServer(http.FS(fsys)))
    s.router.Handle("/assets/AssetManifest.json", http.FileServer(http.FS(fsys)))
    s.router.Handle("/assets/AssetManifest.bin", http.FileServer(http.FS(fsys)))

// omitting many other imported assets
   s.route.Handle("/assets/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.otf", http.FileServer(http.FS(fsys)))

}
```

To avoid making route changes for every additional asset, do I need to recursively crawl the file structure and add them all as routes?

I've tried various approaches of embedding using static/*, static/, static etc.

```
//go:embed static
var staticFiles embed.FS

/* omit code

    s.router.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.FS(fsys)))
```

But I receive 404 File Not Found as browser errors.

Comment: Of course you don't have to list every file!  The [documentation for embed](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) shows a specific example.  Include a complete working example, and maybe we can help you figure out why.